# How can Flash get a variable from a PHP file?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to do a PHP-Flash communication in ActionScript 3. I can send from Flash to PHP
but I don't know how Flash can get a variable from PHP file.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your PHP code is on a server that has PHP enabled, you could do this :

- Instantiate an [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) object (towards your PHP page) in Actionscript 3
- Instantiate an [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) object and make it load your URLRequest
- On completion, retrieve your data from the "data" property of the URLLoader object

Sample code (not tested, might be incorrect AS3 because this is Haxe) :

```
var l : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var rq : URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.example.com/superdata.php");
l.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
l.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, success, false, 0, false);
l.load(rq);

function success (e : Event) : Void {
    trace(e.target.data);
}
```

And on the PHP side of things :

```
<? echo "my data"; ?>
```

Comment: Quick note: To access your variable: `e.target.data.varName`, or throw it into URLVariables object.

Comment: Indeed, this is the workaround, to read the data. but this does not really pass "variables" between. Maybe the question in here is a little bit ambiguous. Anyway, @Antoine good sample on how to handle it

Answer (score 1):

You should use AMFPHP and create a webservice. This way you can have SharedObjects and pass variables back and forth.